# Sentiment docker container can't reach billing endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to run Sentiment analysis from Azure Cognitive Services using an official docker image. Azure Cognitive Service for Language resource is up and running in Azure, but the container can't reach the Billing endpoint.

The container is started as described in the documentation (with the correct billing and key):

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5010:5000 --name sentiment_cmd mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/textanalytics/sentiment Eula=accept Billing=https://RESOURCENAME.cognitiveservices.azure.com/ ApiKey=KEY
```

but in result I always get

```
Failed to reach billing endpoint: 'Resource temporarily unavailable'. Trying 9 more times.
fail: Microsoft.CloudAI.Containers.Http.CloudClient[0]
      Failed to reach billing endpoint: 'Resource temporarily unavailable'. Trying 9 more times.
```

I tried changing the default IP subnet choosen by docker engine, but it didn't fix the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As you are telling the Azure Cognitive Services for Language service is up and running. The problem is with the subnet. Need to check with whether billing endpoint is running with the subnet of the applications is running. Check whether the billing is in private or public subnet and also application is. Even though the service is running and if still it is not responding. Check with the network connections. Check with the network traffic also for the same issue. Reset or recheck the key before connecting.